Probability of success after $t$ draws without replacement
In an urn, there are $Z>2$ balls, with $Q>1$ white and $M=Z-Q$ black.
I want to compute the probability that the $t$-th draw is a white ball. Draws are without replacement.
I have one approach, but I am not sure it is correct. Any help/comment is much appreciated, and I apologize if this is double-posting.
Here is my approach.
For the $1$-st draw, the probability of white is:
\begin{equation}
s_1=\frac{Q}{Q+M} \ .
\end{equation}
Let us now consider the $t$-th draw. The probability of white is:
\begin{equation}
s_t=\frac{Q-x}{Q+M-(t-1)} \ .
\end{equation}
At this point, $t-1$ balls have already been drawn. So the total number of balls (denominator) is $Q+M-(t-1)$. Let $x$ be the number of white balls already drawn. So, the total number of white balls left is $Q-x$.
We need to come up with an expression for $x$.
This is a hypergeometric problem, so the expected number of successes (white balls) after $(t-1)$ draws without replacement should be: $\mathbb{E}[x]=(t-1)\frac{Q}{Q+M}$.
The problem is: If I substitute $x$ with $\mathbb{E}[x]$, $s_t$ reduces to $s_t=\frac{Q}{Q+m}$.
This looks suspicious to me. How can it be that the first draw has the same probability of success as the last? What is my mistake or my mis-interpretation?
Where am I wrong? How can I proceed? Thanks in advance, everyone!

Draw all the balls at random and put them in a line. Is the leftmost ball any more or less likely to be white than the rightmost one?

Same likely @Wei. This suggests solution is correct

@MaB21 Indeed it is correct. There are $Z=Q+M$ equiprobable candidates for the ball that shows up at the $t$-th draw and $Q$ of them are white, so...

Before getting general, try to work out $s_2$ by considering cases (first ball drawn is white, first ball drawn is black).

@JohnDawkins thanks for your comment. I had already computed $s_2$ at the time of my question. But I made a mistake so it was not semplifying to $s_1$ :-) Now everything makes sense. Thanks a lot
